# ios app not rendering webkit to fill space in view per storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I'm a part-time programmer and have not been able to find a solution on point for this dilemma. I have a view controller on my storyboard that I have populated with a webkit view and a toolbar. On the storyboard, the webkit view and toolbar completely fill the page, but when running the app, there is a gap at the bottom of the page. I have tried resetting constraints, adding missing constraints, manually setting constraints, but the gap remains.

How can I simply make these two objects fill the available space?

I apologize, but StackOverflow wont let me post images directly, so im adding the links below:

[App-Screenshot](https://www.myparticip8.com/ssApp.jpg)

[Storyboard-Screenshot](https://www.myparticip8.com/ssStoryboard.png)

Answer (score 0):

Take k blank UIView in your storyboard and add WKWebview in that view programmatically by using addsubview method. Provide the same frame to webview as same as UIView.